# unity 拾うスクリプトを作っているのですが、

Tags: c#, unity3d

やりたいことは、AというタグをもったオブジェクトにプレイヤーのタグがついたオブジェクトがontriggerEnterにひっかかると、アイテムが取得できるという物です。

このスクリプトを拾う予定のオブジェクトに入れると、機能はしますが拾う予定のオブジェクトが無数に存在するので、ゲーム内すべてに適用させる必要があると思うのですが、上の文やり方が分かりません。

一応、タグが同じオブジェクトを取得すればできることは分かっていますが、オブジェクトの数がとても多く重たくなりそうなので、それ以外でお願いします。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
            if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnTriggerEnter() をPickupObjectにではなくプレイヤー側に実装するのははいかがでしょうか。
そうすればオブジェクトが無数にあってもプレイヤーのスクリプトでの実装のみで済むと思わます。

Comment: ありがとうございます　やってみます